# 'come rain, blood, or horse manure' American idiom?

Tags: idioms, american-english

Probably some of you, as I am, are familiar with the controversy that surrounded ABC miniseries [Amerika](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amerika_%28miniseries%29) (February 1987). ABC president response to that controversy  was "we’re going to run that program **come rain, blood, or horse manure**." Surely he did not invent it on the spot; it must be an American saying or related to an American saying. However, my Google research came to no avail! So,

- Is "**come rain, blood, or horse manure**" an American saying?
- If so, what is its origin?

(Please edit-correct any grammar errors).

Comment: *Is "come rain, blood, or horse manure" an American saying?* No.

Comment: @Kris - in what way is my answer wrong?

Comment: @Josh61 Did someone way it was "wrong"? The issue is with the question, and your "answer" would not answer it at all, because neither hyperbole nor horse-manure are the issue here. Please see my comment above. Please also search related previous posts. No hard feelings. :)

Comment: I do think it is an expression used as an hyperbole. The horse manure links are just to provide context where the expression is used idiomatically apart from  the meaning OP is referring to.

Comment: I think the downvote is harsh but justifiable. Googling the [entire phrase](https://www.google.it/search?q=come+rain%2C+blood%2C+or+horse+manure.&oq=come+rain%2C+blood%2C+or+horse+manure.&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22come+rain%2C+blood%2C+or+horse+manure%22.) reveals that it *is* a one-off expression. And at the same time you've answered your own question about its origins! You can of course edit your post, and ask a related question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - sorry but this is what I am saying in my answer ..an expression used just on that occasion (so no idiom) then I add more information on the idiomatic part of that expression (horse manure), specifying that it is not related to the question. I don't see why it is not an answer.. OP is asking if it is an idiom or not!!

Comment: Never heard it before.  Google never heard it before, save for that one quote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line *"come rain, blood, or horse manure"* is but a colourful variant of the idiom

> [**come rain or shine**:](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+rain+or+shine)
>   no matter whether it rains or the sun shines; in any sort of weather
>
> - *Don't worry. I'll be there come rain or shine.*
> - *We'll hold the picnic—rain or shine.*

This one-off variant was coined by ABC president John B. Sias in 1987 after the yet-to-be-aired *Amerika* had generated more controversy and viewer response than any other ABC program in history, including *The Day After*. The miniseries took three years to make and cost nearly $40 million. The story was about the peaceful takeover of the United States by the Soviet Union with the complicity of international 'peacekeeping' troops, whose uniforms and insignia were similar to those of the  U.N. forces.
 <sub>Source: '[Amerika' Sponsor Chrysler Pulls Out](http://articles.orlandosentinel.com/1987-01-28/news/0100330086_1_amerika-chrysler-abc-executives). By New York Times</sub>

The full quote is as follows

> It will not cripple us. It'll hurt us. But we're going to run that program come rain, blood or horse manure.

Using Google's wildcard search, the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=come+rain+or+*&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ccome%20rain%20or%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcome%20rain%20or%20shine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcome%20rain%20or%20snow%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcome%20rain%20or%20come%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcome%20rain%20or%20sun%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcome%20rain%20or%20sunshine%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Ccome%20rain%20or%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcome%20rain%20or%20shine%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bcome%20rain%20or%20snow%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bcome%20rain%20or%20come%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bcome%20rain%20or%20sun%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bcome%20rain%20or%20sunshine%3B%2Cc1) shows that the version with *rain, blood, or manure* is not a common saying nor idiom.

[image]

However, if the OP is curious to know, the earliest instance of "rain or shine" I found on Google Books is dated 1822 in
  [*The Edinburgh Review Or Critical Journal*](https://books.google.it/books?id=YoNHAAAAYAAJ&q=%22rain%20or%20shine%22&dq=%22rain%20or%20shine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=M8MCVcm4DImiygOyuILgCw&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ)

> He who, secure within, can say,
>   To-morrow do thy worst, for I have lived to-day.
>   "Be fair or foul, **or rain or shine**,
>   The joys I have possessed, in spite of fate, are mine;
>   Not Heav'n itself upon the past has power,
>   But what has been, has been, and I have had my hour."

Comment: It could be a variant of  'come what may'  also!!

Comment: Why should it  have been closed ?  It is a fine question. No research shows that is it is an idiom but OP still thinks there may be some relation to other sayings or old expression!! It is just ok!!

Comment: Because now I've shown it is related to the above idiom. Your answer didn't.

Comment: @Josh61 There is a fairly well established expression in Britain, which serves much the same purpose *Come hell or high water*. But it doesn't prevent people making up their own e.g. *Come rivers of blood or a plague of locusts*. The essence seems to me to be to draw on the ridiculous.

Comment: @WS2 I believe that *Come hell or high water* is common to the entire anglosphere. The concessive model of **come *X*** using subject–verb inversion and the archaic present subjective is an ancient one, appearing most often in fixed phrases like *Come the day* or *Come hell or high water*, or with other verbs as in *Be it ever so humble*.

Comment: I believe the traditional one of this genre, as least so far as people around me were concerned was *come hail, rain, or shine*.

Answer (score 0):

I think the expression *blood, rain, or horse manure* is just a [hyperbole](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hyperbole)  used in that specific circumstance to strongly convey the idea that he was going to run the miniseries at any cost.

> - an extravagant statement or figure of speech not intended to be taken literally, as “to wait an eternity.”.

[Horse manure](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/horse-manure)  is used also metaphorically to indicate a nonsensical idea, but it is not related with the meaning used above.

> - (euphemistic) if you describe something such as a statement or idea as horse manure, you are emphasizing that you think it is nonsense   ⇒ 'Sounds like horse manure to me, Mikey boy,' said Ballpark., It's all a load of old horse manure. (Collins)

[Horse manure](https://books.google.it/books?id=5F-YNZRv-VMC&pg=PA527&lpg=PA527&dq=horse%20manure%20american%20idiom&source=bl&ots=mjt0VxaD_q&sig=jyCKmexQP90HNTN9kQV_wuQ_lnU&hl=it&sa=X&ei=838CVeLtN4PfaM2RgvAC&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=horse%20manure%20american%20idiom&f=false): The Routledge Dictionary of Modern American Slang and Unconventional English.

Comment: I would say that "horse manure" refers to the possibility of people throwing same (or it's figurative equivalent) at the TV network ABC.